# React Testing Library - how to test hook that receives nodes

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

In my tets, my hook receives sth like (after consoling):

```
 resultingOptions {
      '$$typeof': Symbol(react.element),
      type: {
        '$$typeof': Symbol(react.memo),
        type: {
          '$$typeof': Symbol(react.forward_ref),
          render: [Function (anonymous)],
          propTypes: [Object],
          __docgenInfo: [Object]
        },
        compare: null
      },
      key: null,
      ref: null,
      props: {
        'data-testid': 'menu-option',
        disabled: false,
        onClick: [Function: onClick],
        children: 'Edytuj dane'
      },
      _owner: null,
      _store: {}
    }
```

I'd like to test if item is disabled or if has text like 'Edytuj dane'

How to test it without using eg `resultingOptions[2].props.children.props.children`?

My wrong test:

```
 expect(resultingOptions).toHaveLength(3);
        expect(
            resultingOptions[0].getByText('Edytuj dane').toBeInTheDocument()
        );
        expect(resultingOptions[0]).props.disabled.toBeFalsy();
```

Anf my hook generates list of menu items in the following structure:

```
<DropdownMenuOption disabled>Edytuj dane</DropdownMenuOption >
```

Comment: Can you show the code of the hook?